# Numpy sum with keepdims argument raises unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I use NumPy `sum` with `keepdims=True` I get an error in the line:

```
np.sum(dZ, axis = 0, keepdims = True)
```

Here is my code:

```py
def linear_backward(dZ, cache):
    """
    Implement the linear portion of backward propagation for a single layer (layer l)

    Arguments:
    dZ -- Gradient of the cost with respect to the linear output (of current layer l)
    cache -- tuple of values (A_prev, W, b) coming from the forward propagation in the current layer

    Returns:
    dA_prev -- Gradient of the cost with respect to the activation (of the previous layer l-1), same shape as A_prev
    dW -- Gradient of the cost with respect to W (current layer l), same shape as W
    db -- Gradient of the cost with respect to b (current layer l), same shape as b
    """
    A_prev, W, b = cache
    m = A_prev.shape[1]

    dW = 1./m * np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T)
    db = 1./m * np.sum(dZ, axis = 1)
    **np.sum(dZ, axis = 0, keepdims = True)**
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T,dZ)

    assert (dA_prev.shape == A_prev.shape)
    assert (dW.shape == W.shape)
    assert (db.shape == b.shape)

    return dA_prev, dW, db
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-072b4a1a94c1> in <module>
----> 1 parameters = two_layer_model(Train_X, Train_Y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2500, print_cost=True)

<ipython-input-39-4058450830f9> in two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate, num_iterations, print_cost)
     42         dA2 = A2 - Y
     43         # Backward propagation. Inputs: "dA2, cache2, cache1". Outputs: "dA1, dW2, db2; also dA0 (not used), dW1, db1".
---> 44         dA1, dW2, db2 = linear_backward(dA2, cache2)
     45         dA0, dW1, db1 = linear_backward(dA1, cache1)
     46 

<ipython-input-38-e06479bad71e> in linear_backward(dZ, cache)
     17     dW = 1./m * np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T)
     18     db = 1./m * np.sum(dZ, axis = 1)
---> 19     np.sum(dZ, axis = 0, keepdims = True)
     20     print(db)
     21     dA_prev = np.dot(W.T,dZ)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)
   1928 
   1929     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
-> 1930                           initial=initial)
   1931 
   1932 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     79                 return reduction(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **passkwargs)
     80             else:
---> 81                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     82 
     83     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
   9582                   min_count=0,
   9583                   **kwargs):
-> 9584         nv.validate_stat_func(tuple(), kwargs, fname=name)
   9585         if skipna is None:
   9586             skipna = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy\function.py in __call__(self, args, kwargs, fname, max_fname_arg_count, method)
     48                 validate_args(fname, args, max_fname_arg_count, self.defaults)
     49             elif method == 'kwargs':
---> 50                 validate_kwargs(fname, kwargs, self.defaults)
     51             elif method == 'both':
     52                 validate_args_and_kwargs(fname, args, kwargs,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_validators.py in validate_kwargs(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
    154     
    155     kwds = kwargs.copy()
--> 156     _check_for_invalid_keys(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
    157     _check_for_default_values(fname, kwds, compat_args)
    158 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_validators.py in _check_for_invalid_keys(fname, kwargs, compat_args)
    125         raise TypeError(("{fname}() got an unexpected "
    126                          "keyword argument '{arg}'".
--> 127                          format(fname=fname, arg=bad_arg)))
    128 
    129 

TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
"""
```

Comment: Which version of numpy do you have?

Comment: can you show the output of type(dZ)?

Comment: looks like `np.sum`  is delegating the task to a pandas dataframe sum method.  Check pandas docs

Comment: I have the 1.18 version on numpy.

Comment: 0             1             2            3            4    \
10904.77 -10671.12795 -10468.929645 -10110.495945 -9714.800545 -9729.606199    

                  693          694         695          696          697  \
10904.77 -4735.070406 -4788.308614 -4662.72423 -4484.689331 -4527.174513   

                  698  
10904.77 -4714.420222  

[1 rows x 699 columns]   This is the output of dZ its a 1x699 vector trying to get it down to 1x1.

Comment: please, add show the output of type(dZ), we need to know if it's a pandas dataframe/series or a numpy array or any other type.